# Deserialize JSON recursively to IDictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to convert some older work to use Newtonsoft JSON.NET. The default handling using the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` method (e.g. if no target type is specified) is to return a `Dictionary<string,object>` for inner objects.

This is actually a really useful basic type for JSON since it also happens to be the underlying type used by `ExpandoObjects` and is the most sensible internal implementation for dynamic types.

If I specify this type, e.g.:

```
 var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
```

JSON.NET will deserialize the outermost object structure correctly, but it returns a `JObject` type for any inner structures. What I really need is for the same outer structure to be used for any inner object-type structures.

Is there a way to specify a type to be used for inner objects, and not just the outermost type returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Deserializing your complex objects using Json, you need to add a JsonSerializer Settings as a parameter. This will ensure that all of the inner types get deserialized properly.

```
    private JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
    };
```

When Serializing your object, you can use the SerializerSettings:

```
    string json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, _jsonSettings)
```

Then when you are deserializing, use:

```
    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json, _jsonSettings);
```

Also, when you serialize, add the JsonSerializerSettings to your SerializeObject(object, settings)

Edit: You can also change the TypeNameHandling and TypeNameAssemblyFormat if you need to. I have them set at 'All' and 'Full' respectively to ensure that my complex objects get serialized and deserialized properly without doubt, but intellisense provides you with other alternatives

Comment: @LukePuplett I don't think this is correct, based on the question asked.

Comment: Based on the question this is not the correct the answer at all.

Comment: Yes, this is not the correct answer. The answer below mentioning creation of a JsonConverter is the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 32):

In order to get Json.Net to deserialize a json string into an `IDictionary<string, object>` including deserializing nested objects and arrays you will need to create a custom class that derives from the `JsonConverter` abstract class provided by Json.Net.

It is in your derived `JsonConverter` where you put the implementation of how an object should be written to and from json.

You can use your custom `JsonConverter` like this:

```
var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(json, new DictionaryConverter());
```

Here is a custom JsonConverter I have used with success in the past to achieve the same goals as you outline in your question:

```
public class DictionaryConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) { this.WriteValue(writer, value); }

    private void WriteValue(JsonWriter writer, object value) {
        var t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        switch (t.Type) {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                this.WriteObject(writer, value);
                break;
            case JTokenType.Array:
                this.WriteArray(writer, value);
                break;
            default:
                writer.WriteValue(value);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void WriteObject(JsonWriter writer, object value) {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        var obj = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var kvp in obj) {
            writer.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key);
            this.WriteValue(writer, kvp.Value);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    private void WriteArray(JsonWriter writer, object value) {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        var array = value as IEnumerable<object>;
        foreach (var o in array) {
            this.WriteValue(writer, o);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        return ReadValue(reader);
    }

    private object ReadValue(JsonReader reader) {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) {
            if (!reader.Read()) throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected Token when converting IDictionary<string, object>");
        }

        switch (reader.TokenType) {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                return ReadObject(reader);
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return this.ReadArray(reader);
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                return reader.Value;
            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException
                    (string.Format("Unexpected token when converting IDictionary<string, object>: {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }
    }

    private object ReadArray(JsonReader reader) {
        IList<object> list = new List<object>();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            switch (reader.TokenType) {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                default:
                    var v = ReadValue(reader);

                    list.Add(v);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return list;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading IDictionary<string, object>");
    }

    private object ReadObject(JsonReader reader) {
        var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            switch (reader.TokenType) {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    var propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();

                    if (!reader.Read()) {
                        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading IDictionary<string, object>");
                    }

                    var v = ReadValue(reader);

                    obj[propertyName] = v;
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return obj;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end when reading IDictionary<string, object>");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return typeof(IDictionary<string, object>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType); }
}
```

Comment: This solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: [Here is this solution on the other post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38029052/1062224)

Comment: This can be simplified by overriding `CanWrite` and returning false as shown in [How to use default serialization in a custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29616596/3744182). Having done that you can just throw an exception from WriteJson, since it won't get called.

Comment: This is the best answer to this question IMO.