# Deserialize JSON string to Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this string:

```
[{ "processLevel" : "1" , "segments" : [{ "min" : "0", "max" : "600" }] }]
```

I'm deserializing the object:

```
object json = jsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

The object looks like:

```
object[0] = Key: "processLevel", Value: "1"
object[1] = Key: "segments", Value: ...
```

And trying to create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic = json as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

but `dic` gets `null`.

What can be the issue ?

Comment: If "json as IDictionary<string, object>", var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString, new ExpandoObjectConverter()); // Maybe ExpandoObject is the dynamic object you were thinking.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

See mridula's answer for why you are getting null. But if you want to directly convert the json string to dictionary you can try following code snippet.

```
    Dictionary<string, object> values = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Comment: but I want to deserialize to a class that has properties as Dictionary and other normal properties. How can I do that?

Comment: For my scenario I noticed that the property was read only. So the deserialization process couldn't set the value.
In my case I changed to not be read only, and it worked!!
But I think you can create a constructor that receive the property, if you prefer to keep it as read only

Answer (score 10):

I like this method:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
//jsonString is your JSON-formatted string
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
Dictionary<string, string> dictObj = jsonObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

You can now access anything you want using the `dictObj` as a dictionary. You can also use `Dictionary<string, string>` if you prefer to get the values as strings.

Comment: Thanks for including the `using` line, too many examples leave that out.

Comment: @Blairg23  In the above example it should be ` jsonObj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();`

Comment: How would you turn the `dictObj` back to a json-formatted string?

Answer (score 7):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) for the `as` keyword states that the statement `expression as type` is equivalent to the statement `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null`. If you run `json.GetType()` it will return `System.Object[]` and not `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`.

In cases like these where the type of object into which I want to deserialize a json object is complex, I use an API like Json.NET. You can write your own deserializer as:

```
class DictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        Throw(new NotImplementedException());            
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Your code to deserialize the json into a dictionary object.

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Throw(new NotImplementedException());   
    }
}
```

And then you can use this serializer to read the json into your dictionary object. Here's an [example](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/).

Comment: This answer on a related problem has the full source code for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31250524/356550

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem and found a solution to it**

- Very simple
- No bugs
- Tested on operational product

Step 1) Create a generic class with 2 property

```
     public class CustomDictionary<T1,T2> where T1:class where T2:class
      {
          public T1 Key { get; set; }
          public T2 Value { get; set; }
      }
```

Step 2) Create New class and inherit from first class

```
  public class SectionDictionary: CustomDictionary<FirstPageSectionModel, List<FirstPageContent>> 
    { 

    }
```

Step 3) Replace Dictionary and List

```
public Dictionary<FirstPageSectionModel, List<FirstPageContent>> Sections { get; set; }
```

and

```
 public List<SectionDictionary> Sections { get; set; }
```

Step 4) Serialize or Deserialize easely

```
 {
     firstPageFinal.Sections.Add(new SectionDictionary { Key= section,Value= contents });
     var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firstPageFinal);
     var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FirstPageByPlatformFinalV2>(str);
 }
```

**Thanks a lot**

Comment: _"No bugs"_ - I can count at least 4 in your code already. Sorry, but I downvoted this answer.

Comment: And what are the 4 bugs?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the object is not of type `Dictionary<string,object>` or a compatible type, thus you can't cast directly. I would create a custom object and use Deserialize.

```
public class DeserializedObject{
    public string processLevel{get;set;}
    public object segments{get;set}
}

IEnumerable<DeserializedObject> object=jsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<DeserializedObject>>(json);
```