# Cannot cast from source type to destination type Json

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm retrieving a json file from my server and then using Json to deserialize the content. How ever I keep receiving this error:

> Cannot cast from source type to destination type

I was following the steps of the Minijson script but yet this error still comes up. Some help would be appreciated.

```
 void Start () {


     //creating url
     image1Request = new WWW("http://development.someurl.com/MoreGames/MoreGames.json");
     StartCoroutine(ImageOne(image1Request));
 }

 IEnumerator ImageOne(WWW www)
 {
     //wait until url is loaded
     yield return www;
     //load image into texture slot
     if (www.error == null)
     {
         //assigning URLS
         var dict = Json.Deserialize(www.text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
         Debug.Log(www.text);
         Debug.Log("deserialized: " + dict.GetType());
         Debug.Log("dict['string']: " + (string)dict["widget"]);

     }

     else
     {
         Debug.Log("WWW Error: " + www.error);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What does `Json.Deserialize` return? It doesn't seem to be a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`var dict = Json.Deserialize(www.text) as Dictionary<string,object>;`

I would suggest you to use the following code snippet

```
var dict = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(); Dictionary<string, object> dictObject =(Dictionary<string,object>)jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(www.text);
```

Comment: Can't find 'Script' under Web.

Comment: What .Net version you are on?

Comment: Oh that's the issue it was added in 4.5 version :( will try to figure out something else

Answer (score 0):

Your Dictionary's value type is `object`. You are trying to cast an `object` type to `string`. It should be corrected to :

```
(object)dict["widget"]
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to log there, but if it is the widget object's name it should go like this :

```
Debug.Log("dict['string']: " + ((object)dict["widget"]).ToString());
```

Comment: Problem is I get the object but not the string that it contains.

Comment: @bru345 What is the type of your object? If your object is a custom type, you'll have to cast it to that type and access the information. Something like
`YourType type = (YourType)dic["widget"]; Debug.log(type.YourString);`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. My Json contains an array which I'm trying to read and save into a dictionary as a string.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve. See if this answers your question.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727787/deserialize-json-string-to-dictionarystring-object)

Comment: Thank you for the link but I'm not having issue with the dictionary returning null. The main root of my problem/understanding is that I cannot read the strings that I have stored in the dictionary. That's ultimately the problem.