# Map properties to a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
    "Item1": {
        "Field1": "Val1",
        "Field2": "Val2"
    },
    "Item2": {
        "Field1": "Val11",
        "Field2": "Val22"
    },
    ....
    "ItemN": {
        "Field1": "Val1",
        "Field2": "Val2"
    },
}
```

I need to deserialize it to a set of classes that look like this:

```
public class Root
{
    public Item Item1;
    public Item Item2;

    public List<Item> Items; // << all the Items should go here
}

public class Item
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
```

How can I make Newtonsoft.Json to map data this way when deserializing?

Comment: Your json should be composed as an array in order for this to work.

Comment: You can deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, Item>` as shown in [Deserializing JSON when key values are unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901245/3744182) or [Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) or [Parsing JSON Object with variable properties into strongly typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202496/3744182).

Comment: In fact this could have been closed as a duplicate of those in 2017.  Was a dictionary not acceptable?  If you need to use a `List<Item>` then do you need to capture the `"ItemN"` names somewhere, or can they be discarded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to populate the `Items` list *and* the individual `Item` properties shown in your `Root` class from the same data in the JSON, then you will need a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to do it.  The following converter should work:

```
public class RootConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Root);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var root = new Root();

        // populate all known Root properties 
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), root);

        // populate Items list with all objects that can be converted to an Item
        root.Items = obj.Properties()
                        .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object && 
                                    (p.Value["Field1"] != null || p.Value["Field2"] != null))
                        .Select(p => p.Value.ToObject<Item>())
                        .ToList();
        return root;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then to use it, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `Root` class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(RootConverter))]
public class Root
{
    public Item Item1 { get; set; }
    public Item Item2 { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items; // << all the Items should go here
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aADhzw

Comment: I do need the root class to map some properties statically.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to not do property mapping manually?

Comment: Sure, you could use `Populate`; see updated answer.

Answer (score 11):

No need for class *Root*. I would deserialize to a Dictionary

```
var dict= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item>>(json);
```

Comment: can you please this a little? how would it map the JS array of objects to a Dictionary and what will the deserialization do here?

Answer (score 2):

From @L.B post: If you need work with Root object you can try this way:

```
public class Root : Dictionary<string, Item>
{
    public List<Item> Items => this.Values.ToList();
}
```

Then you can deserialize JSON to Root object:

```
 var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}
public class Item
{
    public string Field1 {get;set;}
    public string Field2; {get;set;}
}
```

As the classes, and call:

```
Root foobar = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(result);
```

To deserialise.