# Mapping JSON to C# classes when there are multiple keys

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, mapping

I am currently trying to parse the JSON data that I get back from the IEX api, which consists of stocks and their information. The problem I am running into is that depending on which stocks/symbols (ie AAPL, GOOGL etc) you request the keys that are returned change to that symbol. An example of the returned JSON can be seen here: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb,googl&types=quote,chart&range=1m

To deserialize this I am using JSON.NET and the following classes:

```
public class Stock  {
    public quote Quote { get; set;}
    public chart Chart { get; set;}
}

public class Root {
    public Stock[] Stock;
}
```

And then I also have classes for the quote and chart objects. I then deserialize the JSON using:

```
var stocks =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonstring);
```

However, this does not work, but this does work when renaming the 'Stock' class to one of the symbol names, but then only that symbols JSON is parsed. I have no idea what's going on here so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you're using iextrading, have you considered using a library already built so that you don't have to build structures? see https://www.codepoc.io/blog/web-api/5297/get-stock-historical-data-based-on-it-stock-symbol-iextrading-api-c

Comment: Deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, Stock>` as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) or [Parsing JSON Object with variable properties into strongly typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202496).

Comment: You can create your classes like follows: public class AAPL
        {
            [JsonProperty("quote")]
            public Quote Quote;
        }    
        public class Root
        {
            [JsonProperty("AAPL")]
            public AAPL Appl;
        } 
        public class Quote
        {
            [JsonProperty("symbol")]
            public string Symbol;
            // other properties ..
        }

Comment: The method which gets the data from your API: static async Task<String> getStocks()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb,googl&types=quote,chart&range=1m");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  
            return responseBody;
        }

Comment: I've created a simple console app, you can make conversion like this in the Main method: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = getStocks().GetAwaiter().GetResult();              
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(data);
    
            // another method to get deserialized data 
            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
            var obj1 = stuff.AAPL;
            var obj2 = stuff.AAPL.quote;
            var obj3 = stuff.AAPL.quote.symbol;
        }

Comment: I'm not able to add my answer cuz the question has been blocked but hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your class models don't match the json schema of the API output.  The output isn't a list of stocks, it is a mapping of StockName: Stock

You can deserialize it as a `Dictionary<string, Stock>` rather than a `Root` and that should get you where you need to be.