# How to convert JSON to Objects with changing Keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
"Result": 
{
    "AKJB0000001": {
        "BANK": "AKOLA JANATA COMMERCIAL COOPERATIVE BANK",
        "IFSC": "AKJB0000001",
        "BRANCH": "RTGS-HO",
        "ADDRESS": "JANVAIBHAV,OLD COTTON MARKET,AKOLA,PIN 444001",
        "CONTACT": null,
        "CITY": "AKOLA",
        "DISTRICT": "AKOLA",
        "STATE": "MAHARASHTRA"
    },
    "AKJB0000002": {
        "BANK": "AKOLA JANATA COMMERCIAL COOPERATIVE BANK",
        "IFSC": "AKJB0000002",
        "BRANCH": "MALEGAON",
        "ADDRESS": "JANVAIBHAV, MAIN ROAD, MALEGAON PIN 444 503",
        "CONTACT": "271252",
        "CITY": "MALEGAON",
        "DISTRICT": "WASHIM",
        "STATE": "MAHARASHTRA"
    }
}
```

In my `JSON` Key is not constant. I am reading file from `App_Data` and what I am trying to do is returning a `IFSC` matching bank to user using API call

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBankName(string IFSCCode)
{ 
    // here my code goes
}

string IFSCCodeFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ifsc-codes/" + IFSC + ".json");
JObject IFSCCodes = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(IFSCCodeFile));
BankDetails BankList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankDetails>(IFSCCodes.ToString());
```

But **`BankList`** is returning null.

Comment: could you please show your `BankDetails` model?

Comment: In your `BankDetails` declare `Result` to be a `Dictionary<string, T>` as shown in [Deserializing JSON when key values are unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901245/3744182) or [Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) or [Parsing JSON Object with variable properties into strongly typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202496/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below class structure to deserialize your json.

```
class Rooot
{
    public Dictionary<string, BankDetail> Result { get; set; }
}

public class BankDetail
{
    public string BANK { get; set; }
    public string IFSC { get; set; }
    public string BRANCH { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public object CONTACT { get; set; }
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    public string DISTRICT { get; set; }
    public string STATE { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(IFSCCodeFile);

Rooot rooot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rooot>(json);

foreach (var item in rooot.Result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.BANK ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.IFSC ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.BRANCH ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.ADDRESS ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.CONTACT ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.CITY ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.DISTRICT ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.STATE ?? "NULL");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This answer is accepted.

Comment: glad to hear, Then please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get help from Dictionary

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, BankDetails>(yourInput)
```

since your outermost object has result parameter then I suggest you to use class for Deserialization

```
class ResultParser 
{
    IDictionary<string, Bankdetails> Result {get; set;}

}
```

then

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultParser>(yourInput)ş
```