# Getting dynamic JSON values and printing them out

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm getting JSON from an API, each domain like Google, and Facebook will be dynamic. I'm struggling to access the JSON to then put on a webpage, normally APIs are no issue, but the fact its dynamic is causing problems. Furthermore, no solution on StackOverflow is solving my problem. I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object), but unfortunately, it didn't work.

So an example response

```
{
  "data": {
    "google.com": {
      "domain_authority": 95,
      "page_authority": 88,
      "spam_score": 1,
      "nofollow_links": 76221395,
      "dofollow_links": 465226564
    },
    "facebook.com": {
      "domain_authority": 96,
      "page_authority": 100,
      "spam_score": 1,
      "nofollow_links": 97570534,
      "dofollow_links": 565869181
    },
    "wikipedia.org": {
      "domain_authority": 90,
      "page_authority": 75,
      "spam_score": 1,
      "nofollow_links": 1897582,
      "dofollow_links": 20437023
    }
  }
}
```

My code to get the value of Google from the example response:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
// response.Content returns the JSON

var w = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Rootobject>(response.Content);

//trying to echo out Google's Domain Authority.
Response.Write(w.data[0].domain_authority);


public class Rootobject
    {

        public Data data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int domain_authority { get; set; }
        public int page_authority { get; set; }
        public int spam_score { get; set; }
        public int nofollow_links { get; set; }
        public int dofollow_links { get; set; }
    }
```

Latest attempt (working although I cannot get the domains names via JSON):

```
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response.Content);

    var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    var list = root.data.Values;


    int c = 1;
    foreach (var domains in list)
    {
        Response.Write(" "+c+":" + domains.domain_authority);
        c++;
    }

public class Rootobject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Data> data { get; set; }
}


public class Data
{
    public int domain_authority { get; set; }
    public int page_authority { get; set; }
    public int spam_score { get; set; }
    public int nofollow_links { get; set; }
    public int dofollow_links { get; set; }
}
```

Neither of the following work -- and I have a feeling I'm being silly (relatively new to C#, so sorry if it's obvious).

Comment: Use a dictionary: `public Dictionary<string, Data> data { get; set; }` as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Deserializing JSON when key values are unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901245/3744182) or [Deserializing JSON with unknown object names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38688570/3744182) or [Parsing JSON Object with variable properties into strongly typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202496/3744182).

Comment: Also, `JavaScriptSerializer` is deprecated, consider upgrading to [tag:json.net] or [tag:system.text.json].

Comment: @dbc, thank you for your suggestions. I gave  `var w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(response.Content);` a try, and although it didn't fall over, no values were returned at all.

Comment: You need to make the dictionary be a property of your root object: `public class Rootobject { public Dictionary<string, Data> data { get; set; } }`.  Then deserialize the root object as you are currently.  Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oFgVH2

Comment: Still isn't working, this is what I'm seeing: https://gyazo.com/c0e125cd8f8df24e118ac63ec7eb16b3

Comment: Can't see it, seems to require tracking cookies that I have blocked.  Can you [edit] your question to include an updated [mcve]?  Also, take a look at the demo fiddle I included in my previous comment, which deserializes and re-serializes your JSON successfully.  The demo fiddle uses Json.NET but the same data model should work with `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: @dbc, I've updated my question. Just taking a look at your dotnetfiddle & trying to understand it now. :)

Comment: You're still trying to deserialize to a dictionary as your root object rather than trying to deserialize `Rootobject`.

Comment: @dbc, I looked at your dotfiddle and put the pieces together. I'm 99% there, now, instead of doing `{0}` to display a number for each result, how would I get the domains name for each result? As this doesn't seem to be an option?

Comment: Also, I have updated my question to reflect this near-win!

Comment: The dictionary keys are the domain names.  See: [What is the best way to iterate over a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141105/3744182).

Comment: If you'd like to upload your dotfiddle as an answer, I will happily accept it. Very happy indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want an object, leaving it as a JsonDocument is likely an easier and more flexible solution.

```cs
//using System.Text.Json;

JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{  ""data"" : { ""google.com"" : { ""domain_authority"" : 95 }  , ""facebook.com"" : { ""domain_authority"" : 76 }  } }");

JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
JsonElement data = root.GetProperty("data");
foreach (var domain in data.EnumerateObject())
{
  Console.WriteLine($"got domain {domain.Name}, auth {domain.Value.GetProperty("domain_authority")}");
}
```

creates output:

```
got domain google.com, auth 95
got domain facebook.com, auth 76
```

Comment: I don't completely understand this concept, how would you get the values?