# How to deserialize values of a polymorphic dictionary of untyped values into conventional .Net arrays?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class with a property

```
public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }
```

The attribute values can only be strings, numbers, string arrays and number arrays.

I now have a JSON string (without type information) and would like to deserialize it into an object of that class. The problem is that attribute values that are arrays are deserialized into `JArray` objects rather than `string[]` or `long[]`.

How can I perform the deserialization such that the resulting dictionary values of the property "Attribute" are all of type `string`, `long`, `string[]` or `long[]` (or alternatively `object[]` containing strings and longs)?

Comment: Related: [How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5546142/3744182).

Comment: Also related: [Deserialize JSON recursively to IDictionary<string,object> (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11561597/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `Dictionary<string, object>` that adapts the logic from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140420/3744182) to *[How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5546142/3744182)* by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) to return the specific types of arrays required, rather than just `List<object>` collections.

First, define the following converter and extension methods:

```
public class ObjectDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var tokenType = reader.SkipComments().TokenType;
        if (tokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var tempDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var old = reader.DateParseHandling;
        try
        {
            // Disable recognition of date strings
            reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
            serializer.Populate(reader, tempDictionary);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.DateParseHandling = old;
        }

        var dictionary = existingValue as IDictionary<string, object> ?? (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        foreach (var pair in tempDictionary)
            dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToObject());

        return dictionary;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }

    public static object ToObject(this object obj)
    {
        return ToObject(obj as JToken) ?? obj;
    }

    public static object ToObject(this JToken token)
    {
        // Adapts the logic from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140420/3744182) 
        // to https://stackoverflow.com/q/5546142/3744182
        // By [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers)

        if (token == null)
            return null;

        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Null:
                return null;

            case JTokenType.Object:
                return token.Children<JProperty>()
                            .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name,
                                          prop => ToObject(prop.Value));

            case JTokenType.Array:
                {
                    var list = token.Select(t => ToObject(t)).ToList();
                    if (list.All(i => i is long))
                        return list.Cast<long>().ToArray();
                    else if (list.All(i => i is string))
                        return list.Cast<string>().ToArray();
                    else return list.ToArray();
                }

            default:
                return ((JValue)token).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) and deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ObjectDictionaryConverter() },
};
var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttributeObject>(jsonString, settings);
```

Notes:

- Since you know that your dictionary values should be strings rather than `DateTime` values, I disabled Json.NET's automatic date recognition.  For details about date recognition see *[Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zh3PJE).