# Complex json deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I have to deserialize the following json response (the `Result` list has variable length):

```
{
    "ResultSet": {
        "Query": "volkswagen",
        "Result": [
            {
                "symbol": "VLKAY",
                "name": "Volkswagen AG",
                "exch": "PNK",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "OTC Markets",
                "typeDisp": "Equity"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "VOW3.DE",
                "name": "Volkswagen AG",
                "exch": "GER",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "XETRA",
                "typeDisp": "Equity"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "VOW.DE",
                "name": "Volkswagen AG",
                "exch": "GER",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "XETRA",
                "typeDisp": "Equity"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I got:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonString = "...String is here...";
SearchObj obj = js.Deserialize<SearchObj>(jsonString);
```

I understand that I usually have to create a fitting obj. e.g. `SearchObj` which will get filled but in this case I'm not entirely sure how this object is supposed to look like. I came up with:

```
class Data 
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string exch { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string exchDisp { get; set; }
    public string typeDisp { get; set; }
}

class Container 
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Result { get; set; }
}

class SearchObj
{
    public Container ResultSet { get; set; }
}
```

But guess what, it's not working, I only get `ResultSet = null`.

Comment: Do you get a parsing error/exception?

Comment: Why not have a look at dynamics, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: @phoenix7360 No errors/exceptions. Richard I will look into it.

Comment: Does the object not get filled? Do some of the properties get filled?

Comment: @rhughes SearchObj.ResultSet = null -> can't check for any other values. I already did some string fiddling in order to make it easier to parse, since I only need ´Result´ but I would rather like to learn to parse this as well.

Comment: I did ask a similar question. Maybe this can help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903514/147453

Comment: I tested your code and it works: resultset=3

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your class Container as

```
 class Container 
 {
     public string Query { get; set; }
     public Data[] Result { get; set; }
 }
```

I have not tested it, based on my observation

Answer (score 1):

I always feel bad when I answer my own question but here it goes.

Basically my idea was correct, I only made one mistake which is that I don't need the

```
class SearchObj
{
    public Container ResultSet { get; set; }
}
```

Using

```
Container obj = js.Deserialize<Container>(jsonString);
```

instead of

```
SearchObj obj = js.Deserialize<SearchObj>(jsonString);
```

made the trick. Both `Data[]` and `List<Data>` in Container work btw.

Edit:
From giammins comment it seems that it is working on some machines without that change but I guess that's a case for undefined behavior.

Comment: According to your sample JSON, having the external object is more correct... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.json2charp.com to create your classes.