# Deserialize Json String in .Net without creating Type or anonymous type

Tags: .net, json

I have JSON string in following format.

```
{
  "Request": {
    "Header": { "Action": "Login" },
    "DataPayload": {
      "UserName": "user",
      "Password": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to deserialize the above JSON string without creating any Type or Anonymous type and I should be able to access properties like below in .NET.

Request.Header.Action : To get action value.
Request.DataPayload.UserName : To get username.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: you can deserialize it into a dictionary recursively, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781892/how-to-read-dynamic-returned-json-string-in-c/24782326#24782326

Comment: @tt_emrah, No need to manualy convert it to dictionary. JObject already implements `IDictionary`.

Comment: @EZI: oh, i missed that, sorry... however, i remember that they behave differently in case of key not found or null value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Either parse your string as a [`JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and use it like a dictionary:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(str);
var action = obj["Request"]["Header"]["Action"];
```

Or deserialize it into a dynamic object, if you don't mind losing static typing:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);
var action = obj.Request.Header.Action;
```

Comment: dcastro, no need for `<dynamic>`. @HarshanandWankhede how many millions of times do you plan to do this operation to see the difference?

Comment: @HarshanandWankhede Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Factors like readability, flexibility and maintainability are much more important. For those reasons, I'd choose the first option.