# How would I deserialize a json dictionary to its original object type?

Tags: c#, json.net

I wrote the following function:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetObjectPropertiesAsDic<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        return JObject.FromObject(obj).Properties().ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value?.ToString());
    }
```

Which is a one liner to help me converting a type to a dictionary of its properties.
I can't come up with a way (one, two, three... liners ? :) to do the reverse.

Anyone?

Comment: do you need to convert from dictionary to JObject ( vice versa)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JObject into Dictionary<string, object>. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886800/convert-jobject-into-dictionarystring-object-is-it-possible)

Comment: How do you expect to create (and fully populate) an instance of `T` if you do not capture any type information into your Dictionary?

Comment: @MykytaHalchenko: no I want to reverse T -> JObject -> Dictionary. In other words, I want Dictionary -> T.

Answer (score 0):

Add a trick with value serializing:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetObjectPropertiesAsDict<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    return JObject
        .FromObject(obj)
        .Properties()
        .ToDictionary(
                    k => k.Name, 
                    v => v.Value == null ? 
                                null : 
                                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v.Value)
                    );
}

public static T FromDictionary<T>(Dictionary<string, string> dict) where T: new()
{
    T res = new T();
    foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
        {
            prop.SetValue(res,JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dict[prop.Name],prop.PropertyType));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here is example https://dotnetfiddle.net/AMI2Dp

Comment: If you serialize a T1 instance then try to deserialize as T2 it should fail. In your case if T1 and T2 do not have a common property then it will return a new T2 without populating its fields. If they share a common property name but use different data type then it might fail...

Comment: @PeterCsala not always. As example let's take Json.NET serialize/deserialize. If you try serialize class Foo and deserialize result JSON into class Bar it still will be created but it properties will not be assigned. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0OvXe

Comment: Yes, you are right that's the default behaviour. But you can control this loose/strict deserialization via the MissingMemberHandling enum. Setting it to Error would throw an JsonSerializationException.