# Parse any Json into Key value pair

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I tried to read all the Request and response using Fiddler but in some cases I am getting the request data as JSON, and I want to parse that JSON into a key value pair.

I have tried like this

```
string requestPost = Utilities.UrlDecode(oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString());
Dictionary<string, string> jsonRequest = new Dictionary<string, string>();
jsonRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(requestPost);
dataGridViewFiddler.DataSource = jsonRequest;
```

But this didn't work for me.

this is my Json format

```
{"entries":[{"http_response_code":200,"network_changed":false,"protocol":"QUIC","request_age_ms":112425,"request_elapsed_ms":27,"sample_rate":0.05,"server_ip":"216.58.197.78:443","status":"ok","url":"https://www.google-analytics.com/","was_proxied":false}],"reporter":"chrome"}
```

Now if i use dynamic to parse this json its working but

[image]

Comment: Please can you tell us what `requestPost` looks like?

Comment: @Luke requestpost may be any json..

Comment: If your JSON really can be anything at all, then "[How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5546142/10263)" might help you.  But be aware that not every JSON can be parsed into key-value pairs.  If you are starting with an array in JSON, then you will end up with a list when you parse it.

Answer (score 3):

You indicate that you can receive *any JSON*. However, this will result in severe challenges, because you still have to parse your data to use it in some structured way. Therefore you should make sure you always get a similar input. I will give you to options that are best suited.

**Option 1:** De-serializing `JSON` to a `Dictionary` only works if your data follows the `key/value` layout. So the layout should always be like this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

Of course, your value can also be a list. However, the basic layout is still the same. For example:

```
{
    "key1": ["value1", "value2"],
    "key2": ["value3", "value4"]
}
```

This you can just deserialize with your code:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(requestPost);
```

**Option 2:** if your `JSON` data is structured with custom data names, you will have to create corresponding models. A good tool that can put you on the right track for this is [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). Let me give an example. If this is your `JSON`:

```
[{
    "Key": "MyKey",
    "Values": [{
        "First": "RandomValue",
        "Second": "RandomValue"
    }, {
        "First": "RandomValue",
        "Second": "RandomValue"
    }]
},
{
    "Key": "MyKey",
    "Values": [{
        "First": "RandomValue",
        "Second": "RandomValue"
    }, {
        "First": "RandomValue",
        "Second": "RandomValue"
    }]
}]
```

Then your corresponding models should be:

```
public class Value
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}
```

And you can deserialize it like this:

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

**Concluding,** you can either make sure your `JSON` data is structured as a `Dictionary` with `key/value` pairs. In that case you can directly deserialize to a `Dictionary`. Otherwise you will have to create custom models to fit your `JSON` data. Use whatever works best for you! **Please note** that it is possible to just deserialize random data, but it will make it very hard to make sure your code can handle the data! See [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43538090/7397065) on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to deserialize **any JSON**, then the type that you need to deserialize to is simply `dynamic`, not `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` because this would mean that you would have to have a string key in your JSON...

Therefore, to deserialize any JSON object, **as requested**, you need to use the code:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestPost);
```

Bearing in mind that JSON can be as simple as:

```
["bob", "fred"]
```

Which would not match your model, as there is no key (string in your Dictionary).