# Is there a way to specify how you want to Parse certain Properties in Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net

I am currently trying to parse in user data in this form:

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "Tristan Paul",
  "location": {
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "District of Columbia"
  },
  "job": {
    "industry": "Tech",
    "sector": "Tech"
  },
  "experience": 2,
  "frequency": 2,
  "interests": [
    "Social Media",
    "Millenials",
    "Change Management"
  ],
  "role": "Mentor",
  "age": 34
}
```

I want to Parse it into a `Dictionary<string, object>` which I have done with `JObject.Parse(json)` and `object.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()`. When testing the types of each of the values in this Dictionary it produces the following print out.

```
System.String 
System.String 
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject 
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject 
System.Int64
System.Int64
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
System.String
System.Int64
```

What I want to know is, is there a way to specify how the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` are converted as well? Or do I need to iterate through each value and do a `.ToObject<T>()` on them?

Thanks!

**Edit**: 
I am currently am trying to `Deserialize` `Json` to a `Person` object. The `Properties` of this `Person` object look like this.

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("role")]
public string Role { get; set; }

[JsonExtensionData]
public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
```

I am looking for a way to use a `JsonConverter` or `ContractResolver` to specific how each of these extra properties will be added. Same as the problem above for source data and trying to catch those `JObjects` and `JArrays` and convert them to a different type.

I cannot see a way to do this with the `JsonConverter`, am I missing something?

I want to convert the `JArray` to a `String[]` and the `JObjects` to a `Dictionary`.

```
System.String 
System.String 
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject => System.Dictionary<string, string>
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject => System.Dictionary<string, string>
System.Int64
System.Int64
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray => System.String[]
System.String
System.Int64
```

Comment: check `JsonConverter` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm maybe it can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140420/10263)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, followed the code for that answer and it didn't solve my issue unfortunately.