# How do I deserialize a tree of objects into a DTO?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am attempting to deserialize a tree of JSon objects I get back into a DTO. The tree can be up to 4 levels deep, and over 1200 nodes. The code is C# using Newtonsoft.Json for deserialization.

*EDIT*

The JSon looks like:

```
[
{
    "id": 1095,
    "name": "Item1-1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1097,
            "name": "Item2-2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "name": "Item3-3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 19,
                            "name": "Item4-4",
                            "children": [],
                            "level": 4,
                            "parentId": 18
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 20,
                            "name": "Item5-4",
                            "children": [],
                            "level": 4,
                            "parentId": 18
                        }
                    ],
                    "level": 3,
                    "parentId": 1097
                }
                ],
                "level": 2,
                "parentId": 1095
        }
    ],
    "level": 1,
    "parentId": null
}
]
```

My DTO is similar to this:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public MyDTO[] Children { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("parentId")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public MyDTO()
    {
    }
}
```

I like Brian Rogers' solution in this link, which deserializes the json into objects: 
[How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546142/how-do-i-use-json-net-to-deserialize-into-nested-recursive-dictionary-and-list/19140420#19140420)

```
 public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static object Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return ToObject(JToken.Parse(json));
    }

    private static object ToObject(JToken token)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                return token.Children<JProperty>()
                            .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name,
                                          prop => ToObject(prop.Value));

            case JTokenType.Array:
                return token.Select(ToObject).ToList();

            default:
                return ((JValue)token).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the JSonHelper with `object obj = JsonHelper.Deserialize(jsonString);`

I have been experimenting with converting this code into a method to convert to MyDTO, but I keep running into compiler errors. I have attempted to simply convert the JValue casts with MyDTO and move on to the List with a List.

My goal is to call `MyDTO obj = JsonHelp.Deserialize(jsonString)` and get the tree of MyDTO objects back. Is it possible to do what I am trying, or should I find a way to cast each object to MyDTO?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I have edited it to make it more complete. Thanks.

Comment: @gsharp. Thanks that shows that my scrubbing of the data didn't work. Fixing now.

Comment: @Blanthor yeah something wrong in your json... but i always use that helper page to  get a basic structure of the classes and then take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your JSON is missing a  brakcet `]`, then your model needs a nullable `parentId`. Making a couple simple changes you can then you `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyDTO>>(json)`.

So your JSON should look like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1095,
    "name": "Item1-1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1097,
            "name": "Item2-2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "name": "Item3-3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 19,
                            "name": "Item4-4",
                            "children": [],
                            "level": 4,
                            "parentId": 18
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 20,
                            "name": "Item5-4",
                            "children": [],
                            "level": 4,
                            "parentId": 18
                        }
                    ],
                    "level": 2,
                    "parentId": 1095
                }],
            }],
    "level": 1,
    "parentId": null
}
]
```

And can be deserialized with this model:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyDTO[] Children { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Using this code:

```
var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyDTO>>(json);
```

Comment: Both the model and code are compatible with your new valid JSON sample. Thank you for updating the OP.