# IJSRuntime ignores custom json serializer in server side blazor project

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net

In my server side blazor project (core 3, preview6) I'm trying to invoke javascript with an instance of my class. You can do this by injecting a `IJSRuntime` and calling `InvokeAsync` on it (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0)).

Because I need to get rid of all the null properties (the js library that should handle my object (chartJs) cannot handle null values) and because I have some custom serialization (for enums that can have different datatypes), I hacked it to work with an `ExpandoObject` (that was not my idea but it works).

I first serialized my object with json.net so I could define `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` and so all the custom converters got used.

Then I used json.net again to parse it to an `ExpandoObject`. I of course did that because otherwise the values that aren't in the json would be null in the c# instance but this way they aren't present at all.

This `ExpandoObject` which doesn't have the null values and which has the correct enum values, is then used to invoke the javascript. This way there are no null values when it gets to the javascript engine.

[Since in preview6 json.net isn't used internally anymore](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/364) and the new json serializer (from `System.Text.Json`) cannot handle `ExpandoObject`s, I got a runtime error when I updated from preview5 to preview6, saying that `ExpandoObject` isn't supported. No big deal, I made a function to convert an `ExpandoObject` to a `Dictionary<string, object>` which can be serialized without a problem.

Read [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223410/recursive-conversion-from-expandoobject-to-dictionarystring-object-2) to see more about how I did this and to see some examples. This might be a good idea if you don't quite understand what I did. Also it contains the json that I will add in here as well along with the c# model and other explanations.

This works but I thought that maybe if I would be able to get back to json.net I could completely remove the `ExpandoObject` because firstly it would use the custom converters I wrote for my special enums and secondly I could specify `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` globally (ps. would this have sideeffects?).

I followed [the ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support) on how to use json.net again and added this to the `ConfigureServies` method (`services.AddRazorPages()` was already there):

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
    {
        o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(true, false)
        };
    });
```

Sadly it did not work and directly invoking js with the object led to the exact same json (see below) as before I added this.

Then I tried using an `ExpandoObject` directly because I knew the new json serializer from .net can't handle that. As expected it threw an exception and the stacktrace shows no signs of json.net. This confirms that it's not actually using json.net like I told it to.

> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonClassInfo.GetElementType(Type propertyType, Type parentType, MemberInfo memberInfo)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonClassInfo.CreateProperty(Type declaredPropertyType, Type runtimePropertyType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type parentClassType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonClassInfo.AddProperty(Type propertyType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type classType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonClassInfo..ctor(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerOptions.GetOrAddClass(Type classType)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.GetRuntimeClassInfo(Object value, JsonClassInfo& jsonClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.HandleEnumerable(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(PooledByteBufferWriter output, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.WriteCoreString(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.ToString[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeBase.InvokeAsync[T](String identifier, Object[] args)
>      at ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.ChartJsInterop.GetJsonRep(IJSRuntime jSRuntime, Object obj)

I then also tried just changing the options from the normal serializer to see if that would change anything. I used this instead of `AddNewtonsoftJson`:

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);
```

Interestingly this still gave me the same result.

I will add the json that got produced along with what should be produced. You can also find this in the CodeReview question I mentioned earlier.

The following json is what I get:

It stays the same when

- I don't specify anything in the `ConfigureServices` method.
- I specify to use `Newtonsoft.Json` through `AddNewtonsoftJson`.
- I specify the `JsonOptions` from .net through `AddJsonOptions`.

```
{
    "options": {
        "someInt": 2,
        "someString": null,
        "axes": [
            {
                "someString": null
            },
            {
                "someString": "axisString"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "data": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        ],
        "someString": "asdf",
        "someStringEnum": {}   <-- this is one of those special enums with a custom converter
    }
}
```

This is what I should get. Notice all the null values are removed and the custom converter is used. I was only able to get this with my hacky solution that uses the `ExpandoObject`.

```
{
    "options": {
        "someInt": 2,
        "axes": [
            {},
            {
                "someString": "axisString"
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "data": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        ],
        "someString": "asdf",
        "someStringEnum": "someTestThing"   <-- this is one of those special enums with a custom converter
    }
}
```

**So why is it still using `System.Text.Json` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json` even though I instructed it to? What else do I have to add to make it use json.net?**

Comment: Checking the [reference source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop/src/JSRuntimeBase.cs#L43), the method getting called, `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeBase.InvokeAsync`, seems hardcoded to use `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer`.   You may need to make your own `IJSRuntime`.

Comment: Damn :( But how could I create my own? I assume there is a rather big ecosystem around injecting the jsruntime in javascript right?

Comment: Since you're injecting your own `IJSRuntime`, maybe you could use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and create some wrapper to a "real" `IJSRuntime` that serializes & preprocesses the args into a clean neutral format?  I.e. `arg` -> `JToken` (via serialization options) -> `Dictionary<string, object>` as shown in [How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19140420).

Comment: Should I make that an answer?

Comment: "Since you're injecting your own `IJSRuntime`.." I'm not, I have absolutely nothing to do with what is being injected. That's all from .net itself and I have no control over that. I don't even know what type is actually being injected since I ask for an interface. Also this "serializing & preprocessing the args into a clean neutral format" is exactly what I'm doing currently with the solution that uses `ExpandoObject`. I would like to get rid of that though because using `ExpandoObject` this way is very hacky and it would be **a lot** better if I could avoid that.

Comment: Sorry @dbc. I think I did not fully understand what you tried to tell me. Your solution would probably work and some of my claims were simply inaccurate. I have not tried it but while searching for a solution to this issue and writing [a new feature request for this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12685) I think I finally understood what you mean. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly mentioned in the comments by @dbc, `IJSRuntime` always uses `System.Text.Json`. I have confirmed this by asking the asp.net team about it (see [my github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11954)).

I submitted a [github feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12685) which might make this possible in future .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended deserializing to `JsonElement` and then applying deserialization with custom options like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents structure of the received context message.
/// </summary>
[<CLIMutable>]
type TeamsContext = {
    /// <summary>
    /// Json of Content Action Info
    /// </summary>
    ActionInfo : JsonElement Skippable
    /// <summary>
    /// Properties about the current session for your app
    /// </summary>
    App : JsonElement
}

type TeamsContextReader(ctx : TeamsContext, options : JsonSerializerOptions) =
    let actionInfo =
        ctx.ActionInfo
        |> Skippable.toValueOption
        |> ValueOption.map (fun json -> lazy json.Deserialize<ActionInfo>(options))
    let app = lazy (ctx.App.Deserialize<AppInfo>(options))

    /// <summary>
    /// Content Action Info
    /// </summary>
    member _.ActionInfo : ActionInfo voption =
        actionInfo |> ValueOption.map (fun info -> info.Value)
    /// <summary>
    /// Properties about the current session for your app
    /// </summary>
    member _.App : AppInfo = app.Value
```