# Issue with serializing 'object' with System.Text.Json

Tags: json.net, .net-5, system.text.json

I need to store an unknown JSON structure from an external API, but when I serialize the data using `System.Text.Json`, the JSON output is incorrect. A working example can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0zBAs

Example data from external API:

```json
[{"name":"source","choices":["Email","Portal","Phone","Forum"]}]
```

Output from `System.Text.Json.Serialize`

```json
[{"name":"source","choices":[[],[],[],[]]}]
```

**Why doesn't this serialize properly?**

Initially, I deserialize the data from the external API to a class similar to the one below using the `Newtonsoft` library because it does a better job of deserializing the data than `System.Text.Json`. Interestingly, `Newtonsoft` will correctly serialize the data.

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name"), System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("choices"), System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("choices")]
    public object Choices { get; set; }
}
```

The `Choices` data I receive could be any type but I have noticed they are commonly one of these:

- `Dictionary<string, string[]>`
- `string[]`
- `Dictionary<string, int>`
- `Dictionary<string, long>`

I have a feeling it is something to do with this Microsoft article on [migrating from Newtonsoft.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#deserialization-of-object-properties), but I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to serialize a Newtonsoft `JToken` with `System.Text.Json`, which is not supported.  You could use the same serializer for deserialization and subsequent serialization, or use the converter from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386084/3744182) to [How can I serialize a Newtonsoft JToken to JSON using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65386083/3744182).  In fact this might be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Yeah that converter works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/TBecoo.  Still, mising `JToken` and `System.Text.Json` seems like a bad idea in the long run.  It might be better to convert the `JToken` to a native .Net object along the lines of [How do I use JSON.NET to deserialize into nested/recursive Dictionary and List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5546142/3744182).

Comment: hanks for that link.. I agree that it is a similar question, however I forgot to mention that the data is stored as a string in a database between serialization/deserialization so `Choices` property would be treated as plain object when serializing back to `TestClass`.

Comment: So is your real requirement that to have a property `public string Choices` that is serialized and deserialized as "raw" json by both Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json?  Can you please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing your precise requirements?

Comment: We are using an Entity Framework `ValueConverter` so that the object is converted to a JSON string using `System.Text.Json.Serialize` before being stored in the database. My [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0zBAs) also serializes/deserializes using just the `System.Text.Json` library which produces the same results. My requirement is that `Choices` is correctly serialized to a JSON string like `Newtonsoft` handles it. From your answers I believe this can be done with custom `JsonConverter`.

Comment: Yes, the `JTokenConverterFactory` from the linked answer will correctly serialize any `JToken` subclass (other than `JConstructor` which is not part of the JSON standard) to `System.Text.Json`.