# .net core returns empty body json on Get request

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

Having troubles to return json .net core 6.0 C#
I'm using NewtonSoft json library
Obviously I'm doing something wrong...

```
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;

static JObject j_tmp = new JObject();

private static async Task<IResult> Command1()
{
   j_tmp["test"] = "1234";
   j_tmp["number"] = 18;
   //return Results.Json(j_tmp ); //Doesn;t work, empty body
   //return Results.Json(j_tmp.ToString()); //Doesn't work, adds "\r\n" on each break line
   return Results.Content(j_tmp.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None), "application/json; charset=utf-8"); //WORKS
            
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a **`static`** `JObject`?  You could have all sorts of thread-related issues thanks to that.

Comment: Your basic problem however is that asp.net core in 3.1 and later no longer uses Newtonsoft by default, it uses System.Text.Json.  If you want to go back to Json.NET see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182) to [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182).  If you don't want to go back to Newtonsoft, we need to know the precise version of asp.net core you are using.

Comment: See also [Response JObject values not completely filled in returned JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67819154) which looks to be related or duplicate.  Note that the accepted answer has a bug, namely that the `JsonDocument` returned is never disposed.  If you are working in .NET 6 it would be better to use the [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter#use-jsonnode) to construct your JSON object directly.

Comment: Does that possible duplicate answer your question?   Or do you need a specific answer?

Comment: Thanks dbc, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67819154 really seems to be related, but under the hood it does similar to return Results.Content(j_tmp.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None), "application/json; charset=utf-8"). I'm working with .NET 6 Is there any chance to go back to Json.Net? adding nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson and services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(); didnt help

Comment: *adding nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson and services.AddControllers() .AddNewtonsoftJson(); didnt help* -- that's surprising.  We need to see a [mcve] to figure out what is going on on there.  In fact that's really a separate question, so you might want to ask another one.  Also, be sure to [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) that question with the appropriate framework and version, e.g. [tag:asp.net-core-6.0]. Or you could [edit] your current question, but would you like an answer to this question with some alternatives to `JObject`?

Answer (score 0):

> when I return JObject object, it appears empty on receiving (frontend)
> side

Maybe you want a way to pass the JObject object from contoller to the view ?

If so, you can refer to below demo.

In controller:

```
static JObject j_tmp = new JObject();
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            j_tmp["test"] = "1234";
            j_tmp["number"] = 18;
            ViewBag.j_tmp= j_tmp;   
            return View(j_tmp);
        }
```

In the view:

```
@ViewBag.j_tmp
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
private static async Task<JsonResult> Command1()
{
   j_tmp["test"] = "1234";
   j_tmp["number"] = 18;
   //return Results.Json(j_tmp ); //Doesn;t work, empty body
   //return Results.Json(j_tmp.ToString()); //Doesn't work, adds "\r\n" on each break line
   return Json(new JsonResult(null, new { test = j_tmp["test"], number = j_tmp["number"] }));
            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume you are working on ASP.NET Core project (as your question mentioned a `GET` request) and you are asking how to return a simple json.

The simplest way is to return an anonymous object in your action method.

In your controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult YourAction() 
{
    return OK(new { test = "1234", number = 18 });
}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: No. My problem is that when I return JObject object, it appears empty on receiving (frontend) side.